# add a contact opening the address book app

Tags: android, contacts, addressbook

What should I do if I want to add a contact without saving it? For example: I want to populate the fields of the address book with values received from my app. Like when you add a contact with Whatsapp (it fills the field of the phone number but it doesn't save the contact). Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

**UPDATE:**

I've already tried this, but it directly save it!

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
            .build());

    // add contact name
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)              
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,contatto).build());
try 
    {
        getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.Contattoaggiuntocorr),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {               
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**SOLVED!**

I found the solution!

```
public void insertContact(String name, String email) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.setType(Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.NAME, name);
intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.EMAIL, email);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: You want to save a contact to the `contacts.db` file on the Android device but not save it? This is what the Android API is going to do. What have you tried?

Comment: I've just updated the post

Comment: This really is not possible. You would have to add then delete it.

Comment: No no, you don't understand. I want to open the address book app and fill all the fileds I want and the user has only to tap on "save"

Comment: Please update your question title, you already have 2 closed votes because users do not understand.